# ORA-01722: invalid number Error

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, ora-01722

I am facing titled error while execution of below query.

```
select to_number('FROM1', 'xxxxxxx') from dual;
```

> Error ORA-01722: invalid number

`FROM1` values can be:

```
F1F65
F20B5
F204D
```

Please suggest solution. I need to convert these values to a number. For example, F1F65 will be converted to 991077 using below query.

```
select to_number('F1F65', 'xxxxxxx') from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
select to_number(FROM1, 'xxxxxxx') from dual;
```

otherwise Oracle interprets FROM1 as a string, and not as a variable.

Comment: that comes with error ORA-00904: "F2730": invalid identifier

Comment: @Dogar, what's FROM1? A variable, or column, or...?

Comment: @jarlh, its variable. Gets value when BINARY executed from backend.

Comment: @Dogar, if its a variable there should be no single quotes.

Comment: @Dogar, then you should edit your post to adde the contest in which FROM1 is defined/assigned. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_number(hex_value,'xxxxxxx')  
  from hex;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb1feb/1)